# Log file is not containing the database errors in liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1 and while configuring the database to mysql database in console it is giving error as innoDB is having row level logging enabled so unable to execute the query...etc..
But surprisingly I am not able to see these logs in any of the files.
I have checked {TOMCAT_HOME}/logs directory and {LIFERAY_HOME}/logs directory. But none of the files are containing the error logs.
If anybody can assist me on is there any other place to look for the logs, that will be really helpful.

Shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now.
In mysql db the setting for binlog_format is "STATEMENT'
I changed it to ROW and it started running.
The syntax:
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

The blank database you have created might not have enough permission, you would need to give full permission i.e. to allow write / execute.

So that while you configure Liferay to point this blank database it will create table which requires write permission.

Comment: Logs can be found at 2 places {liferay home dir}/logs and {liferay home dir}/tomcat/logs